# How to add an item into listview after binding?

Tags: listview, winjs

I'm trying to add an item into listview after binding, but i didt find a solution.

I don't want to write a custom control.

I will use to make "Get More" button.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you using WinJS.Binding.list as your data source? If so, it acts like an array, just do:

```
myData.push(newItem);
```

and it'll show up in the listview at the end of the list. You can use the `splice` method if you want to stick the new item somewhere in the middle.